# Событие срабатывает только на одном элементе из двух бутстрап, js (не jquery)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, bootstrap4, popup

Есть два алерта в бутстрап-4:

```
<div id="success_alert" class="alert col-6 mx-auto alert-success alert-dismissible fade fixed-top" role="alert">
    <span></span>
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="alert_close(this.parentNode)" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
<div id="errors_alert" class="alert col-6 mx-auto alert-danger alert-dismissible fade fixed-top" role="alert">
    <span></span>
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="alert_close(this.parentNode)" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
```

Они встроены в конце и вызываются по надобности меняя содержимое внутри. С вызовом все отлично, а вот закрыть получается только одно (второе по списку), другое не реагирует

```
//закрывает, а не уничтожает popup
const alert_close = element => element.classList.remove('show')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const alert_close = element => element.classList.remove('show')
```

```css
.alert {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="success_alert" class="alert col-6 mx-auto alert-success alert-dismissible fade fixed-top show" role="alert">
  <span></span>
  <button type="button" class="close" onclick="alert_close(this.parentNode)" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
<div id="errors_alert" class="alert col-6 mx-auto alert-danger alert-dismissible fade fixed-top show" role="alert">
  <span></span>
  <button type="button" class="close" onclick="alert_close(this.parentNode)" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ответ из категории "найдите 10 отличий".